# Don't understand cause of TypeError in my bingo game simulator

Tags: python

It gives me this error:

```
    for s in lista[pl]["schede"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Python code:

```
#import
import random
#---------------
#data
list1 = []
extracted = {"tot":0,"number":[]}
cards = int(input("# cards= "))
player = int(input("# player= "))
winner = ' '
#---------------
#code
for pl in range(player):
    name = input("enter player name= ")
    list1.append({"name": name, "cards":[]})
    for sc in range(cards):
        list1[pl]["cards"].append([])
        i = 0
        while i != 15:
            num = random.randint(1, 90)
            if not num in list1[pl]["cards"][sc]:
                list1[pl]["cards"][sc].append(num)
                i += 1
for n in range(90):
    num = random.randint(1, 90)
    if not num in extracted["number"]:
        extracted["tot"] += 1
        extracted["number"].append(num)
        for pl in list1:
            **for s in list1[pl]["cards"]:**
                for e in list1[pl]["cards"][s]:
                    if num in list1[pl]["cards"][s]:
                        list1[pl]["cards"][s][list1[pl]["cards"][s].index(num)] = 0
                        if sum(list1[pl]["cards"][s]) == 0:
                            winner = list1[pl]["name"]
print("The winner is=",winner,"\nThe numbers drawn are=",extracted["tot"])
```

Comment: Try being more specific with the question and describe attempts you have already made to answer the question. Also, try to provide the line number being called out for the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're already getting each `pl` dictionary from `list1` via:

`for pl in list1:`

You can't use a list's item as a list index. So, `list1[pl]` will fail since `pl` is a dictionary. It's unnecessary to do `list1[pl]` since `pl` is already an item from `list1`.

You just need to do this:

```
for pl in list1:
  for s in pl["cards"]:
```

So, everywhere else where you're doing `list1[pl]`, you need to replace it with just `pl`.

Comment: thanks, now it gives me the same error in the next line

Comment: Yeah that's because you're making the same mistake on that line, as well as other lines. You have to fix all such instances. I can point out the error but you should be learning from my answer, understanding why the error is there, and applying the fix to anywhere that the error exists. If you don't understand it I can explain in more detail, but I assumed you'd realize you had that mistake in several places.

Comment: yeah, i've fixed, now i've another problem, i'm gonna try from myself